# Open ID Connect Multiple response types

Tags: openid-connect

With Open ID Connect, what is the value of the `code id_token token` response type when using the hybrid flow?

This returns a response containing an authorisation code, identity token and access token. Given you already have the access token in the response, the authorisation code is redundant?

Answer (score 1):

You can get a refresh token at the `token` endpoint using the authorization code.

Answer (score 0):

Answer for this can vary on the exact implementation. This is justifiable by what OpenID Connect specification mentions in the protocol document.

There is a dedicated **[token endpoint](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#HybridTokenEndpoint)** explanation given under Hybrid flow. According to that,

> **[ID Token](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#HybridIDToken2)**
>
> When using the Hybrid Flow, the contents of an ID Token returned from the Token Endpoint are the same as for an ID Token returned from the Authorization Endpoint

There are few exceptions like,

- Omitting `at_hash` and `c_hash` Claims in Id token from token endpoint
- Restricted (limited) claims in Id token from authorization endpoints

Now that second one is implementation specific. So you might find few differences or you may see them as identical.

Unless you have special requirement, I recommend to  stick with authorization code flow. It is more secure and even OAuth working group suggests not to obtain tokens from authorization response (i.e - Implicit flow).